# Weingarten function for unitary group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, symmetric-groups

Studying integration over unitary group I came across this function, the Weingarten function Wg, such that
$$ \int_{\mathcal{U}(N)} \prod_{k=1}^{n} U_{i_kj_k}
U^*_{m_k r_k} dU=\sum_{\tau,\sigma\in S_n} {\rm
Wg}^U(\tau^{-1}\sigma)\prod_{k=1}^n \delta_{i_k,\tau(m_k)}\delta_{j_k,\sigma(r_k)}.$$ I understand the structure of this equation, the $m$'s must be a permutation of the $i$'s, and likewise the $r$'s with the $j$'s. However, the function itself is complicated, 
$$ {\rm
Wg}(\tau^{-1}\sigma)=\frac{1}{n!^2}\sum_{\substack{\lambda\vdash n\\\ell(\lambda)\leq N}}
\frac{d_\lambda^2}{s_\lambda(1^N)}\chi_\lambda(\tau^{-1}\sigma),$$ where $s_\lambda$ are Schur functions, $d_\lambda$ is the dimension of a irreducible representation of the permutation group labelled by $\lambda$ and $\chi$ are the characters of the irreps of this group. The derivations I have seen of this result are also complicated.

Can anyone offer some insight into this function and how it is derived?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend [Elementary derivation of Weingarten functions of classical Lie groups](http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.2182) by Marcel Novaes (2015).

> Previous works where Weingarten functions were obtained were based
>   either on representation theory and Schur-Weyl duality, the theory of
>   Gelfand pairs, or Jucys-Murphy elements. In contrast, we here derive
>   Weingarten functions for the classical compact groups by means of some
>   elementary direct calculations (although we rely on some classical
>   results that can, of course, be interpreted very naturally in the
>   light of those theories).
>
> The idea consists of five steps: 1) write the integrand as the
>   derivative of a power sum function; 2) change basis from power sums to
>   Schur functions; 3) perform the group integral; 4) revert back to
>   power sums; 5) take the derivative to arrive at the result.

Comment: Glad to see my paper helped someone. It was rejected by the journal for not being novel enough...